# Symfony: How to include custom functions in the view

Tags: view, symfony1, include, symfony-1.4

I have a populated list, and I want to utilize a custom function to shorten row names which are too long to display. The rows from the list are generated from an object passed from the action/controller. How/where do I include my custom function for to achieve the above mentioned purpose?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Should you not be shortening them in the controller before you pass it over to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need helpers:

http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/07-Inside-the-View-Layer

Answer (score 1):

Use this function in _toString method of the object to display its name.